# Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following CSP directive

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments, content-security-policy

I am trying to integrate Stripe to my website, the problem is that I receive the following error:

> **js.stripe.com/v3/hcaptcha-invisible-078b5f9fb44d244a9ec072f93a216630.html#debugMode=false&parentOrigin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:3 [Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-CBu0w5uiOaPgb2R6Zgf7E0+STJHF4lcPIdhZzQXE6yk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.**

I tried to solve it using the `Stripe directives` in this way:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' js.stripe.com code.jquery.com cdn.jsdelivr.net maps.googleapis.com  'unsafe-inline';">`

But because the location of the file that is given the error is on the `Stripe server`, I think that those rules of the  are not applied to that file.

I have made other integrations of  give the same approach error to make sure, and I have solved it by putting the directives in the  and it works, but I have not been able to solve the error described above.

If you want to see the same error, you just have to go to this `Stripe link` and inspect the browser in the console.

[Link](https://js.stripe.com/v3/hcaptcha-invisible-078b5f9fb44d244a9ec072f93a216630.html#debugMode=false&parentOrigin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost)

Comment: Which integration flow do you use? Payment Element, Checkout Session... etc?

Comment: Can you share your development website, or code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Having the same problem starting about two weeks ago in a long-established stripe installation.  Sales are still going through though.

Comment: What version of the Stripe API are you using?  And if an older version where Link is in beta, are you using the link beta?

Comment: @MichaelScottAsatoCuthbert 
Yes, the funny thing is that sales are still working normally, but the error keeps appearing. I am using version **13.6.0**

Comment: @yuting

I am using Payment Element you can see it here:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart)

To see the error this is the link:

https://js.stripe.com/v3/hcaptcha-invisible-078b5f9fb44d244a9ec072f93a216630.html#debugMode=false&parentOrigin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost

Just go to the link and inspect elements with your browser console. I don't think that by trying to replicate the code and trying to build a form you can see the error, since apparently the error is activated after Stripe identifies some anomaly in the use of the API.

Comment: I'm able to see the same at my side. Looks like CSP directives in StripeJS might have some issues. I'd recommend writing into Stripe [Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) to ask them to have a check.

Comment: @yuting

It's the same thing I thought, I tried to talk to them, but apparently the person who receives my calls is not a person who can directly solve that problem. In any case, I will leave something here to warn others that it is not necessarily a problem in their codes.

Comment: btw -- my company upgraded to the newest API version (2023-11-something) and the problem continues.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I don't see any CSP error on hcaptcha-invisible.

Comment: @yuting I just saw that, apparently Stripe support did something to correct it, I'll leave something here to inform others how it was solved so they don't rack their brains thinking that they themselves are making some mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the new ones who came here after this answer, you can try all the solutions that other people have already posted here if you are getting a CSP error from a file that you saved locally and can fully manage and edit. If the file that is giving you the error is hosted in a directory in the cloud to which you do not have access to make edits, as was my case with the Stripe API, then what you have left is to request help from the support that manages said file which returns a CSP error.

**Thanks to @Mr. Cockadookie, @Henry Sneed, @Halvor Sakshaug, @Yuting, and @Michael Scott Asato Cuthbert, for showing interest in this.**

Answer (score 4):

Somewhere the "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only" response header is being set. As it is "Report-Only" (you can see this in the error message) nothing is actually blocked due to this policy, this is why it still works. But adding another policy in a meta tag doesn't change anything because content needs to pass all CSPs present. You will need to identify how/where the report only policy is being set and modify it before enforcing it by changing it to just "Content-Security-Policy". You could add 'unsafe-inline', but it is of course unsafe. You could add the suggested hash value 'sha256-CBu...', which will work if it is outputting static code and as long as the code doesn't change.

Answer (score 3):

#### Summary

To enable the API connection between your application and Stripe you can change the **Content Security Policy** by modifying your application's HTTP headers. To do this for a **next.js** application, I did the following within **next.config.js**. If you're using a different Javascript framework you will likely need to set the same headers using whatever configuration regime your framework uses. Also, when in a dev environment I am using the unsafe-eval header.

#### Example Config

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
            value: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
              ? "script-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com; frame-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com; connect-src 'self' https://api.stripe.com"
              : "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://js.stripe.com; frame-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com; connect-src 'self' https://api.stripe.com",
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

#### Documentation

**Next.js Headers**: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/headers

**Stripe CSP**: https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and very concerned. However, the Report Only is designed for testing policies and is supposed to simulate a policy, so I don't believe it's actually having any affect on the inline script itself.